# how can i know which options are selected each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

```
<div class="nav" data-index="0">
 <a class="square_option">List 1, item 1</a>
 <a class="square_option">List 1, item 2</a>
 <a class="square_option">List 1, item 3</a>
 <a class="square_option">List 1, item 4</a>
 <input class="quantity" type="text" data-index="0"/>
</div>
<div class="nav" data-index="1">
 <a class="square_option">List 2, item 1</a>
 <a class="square_option">List 2, item 2</a>
 <a class="square_option">List 2, item 3</a>
 <input class="quantity" type="text" data-index="1"/>
</div>
<div class="nav" data-index="2">
 <a class="square_option">List 3, item 1</a>
 <input class="quantity" type="text" data-index="2"/>
</div>
```

How can I know when I select the first 4 options the quantity in `data-index="0"` is 1, when I select the following 3 options the quantity in `data-index="1"` is 1 ... when I select an option i add the following class "square-option-select"

---

*Added clarifications from comments*

> In each group I have n number of options, if you select all the
>   options the quantity has to change to 1, in each group.
>
> Only the quantity element of group 1, then if i select all options in
>   group 2 quantity element of group 2 should be 1.

Comment: Post your code please you are having trouble with so we can have a look and see what the problem might be. - Also, I don't understand what it is you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to check which `quantity` element the selected `option` elements belong to? What if you have 1 in each "group" selected, what is it you expect then?

Comment: In each group I have n number of options, if you select all the options the quantity has to change to 1, in each group

Comment: If I select all options in group 1 do you want **all** `quantity` elements' `data-index` to be set to `1` or only the `quantity` element of group 1? - If that is so you should be able to solve this using your code you posted earlier using `sibling` selectors.

Comment: only the quantity element of group 1, then if i select all options in group 2 quantity element of group 2 should be 1

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav').each(function(index_block, item_block){   
    $('.square_option', this).on('click', function(index_opcion, item_opcion){
        if($(this).hasClass('square-option-select')){                           
            if(index_opcion == 3 && index_block == 0){                                      
                $('.quantity[data-index="' + index_block + '"]').val(1)                 
            } else if(index_opcion == 2 && index_block == 1){
                $('.quantity[data-index="' + index_block + '"]').val(1)
            } else if(index_opcion == 0 && index_block == 2){
                $('.quantity[data-index="' + index_block + '"]').val(1)
            }               
        }
    });
});
```

i got this but only works when you select the last child

Answer (score 0):

> In each group I have n number of options, if you select all the options the quantity has to change to 1, in each group

*There is most likely much better and more elegant ways of doing this then the below but you should be able to take that working example and get it working in your own code.*

---

You can do that using `siblings` similar to this:

```
$('.square_option').on('click', function() {
    var $currentOption = $(this);
    $currentOption.toggleClass('square-option-select');

    var allOptions = $currentOption.siblings('.square_option').add($currentOption);

    var selectedOptions = allOptions.filter(function() {
        return $(this).hasClass('square-option-select')
    });

    var quantity = $currentOption.siblings('.quantity').eq(0);
    var allSelected = allOptions.length === selectedOptions.length;

    quantity.val(allSelected ? 1 : '');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.square_option').on('click', function() {
    var $currentOption = $(this);
    $currentOption.toggleClass('square-option-select');

    var allOptions = $currentOption.siblings('.square_option').add($currentOption);

    var selectedOptions = allOptions.filter(function() {
      return $(this).hasClass('square-option-select')
    });

    var quantity = $currentOption.siblings('.quantity').eq(0);
    var allSelected = allOptions.length === selectedOptions.length;

    quantity.val(allSelected ? 1 : '');
  });
});
```

```css
.square_option {
  display: block;
}
.square-option-select {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav" data-index="0">
  <a class="square_option">List 1, item 1</a>
  <a class="square_option">List 1, item 2</a>
  <a class="square_option">List 1, item 3</a>
  <a class="square_option">List 1, item 4</a>
  <input class="quantity" type="text" data-index="0" />
</div>
<div class="nav" data-index="1">
  <a class="square_option">List 2, item 1</a>
  <a class="square_option">List 2, item 2</a>
  <a class="square_option">List 2, item 3</a>
  <input class="quantity" type="text" data-index="1" />
</div>
<div class="nav" data-index="2">
  <a class="square_option">List 3, item 1</a>
  <input class="quantity" type="text" data-index="2" />
</div>
```

---

Additional [**Plunker**](http://embed.plnkr.co/BixBRpkmlkWq8v3JJYZf/)